# Submit form with file input return validation error in Laravel 5.1.*

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have this form

```
<form class="" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{route('submit_prop')}}" method="POST">
<div class="margin-btm-sm">
    <label>Main Image</label>
    <input type="file" name="main_img" class="form-control" />
</div>

  <div class="margin-btm-sm">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</div>
</form>
```

when submit the form the request array (POST array) is empty. but when remove enctype="multipart/form-data" from form

```
<form class="" action="{{route('submit_prop')}}" method="POST">
```

the request array has data.

Controller Method:

```
   function submit(SubmitPropRequest $request, $id=null) {
              dd(\Request::all());
   }
```

Request Contoller:

```
 public function rules()
{  
         dd(\Request::all());  
    return [
        'main_img' => 'image|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg',
    ];
}
```

what is the issue? i know the enctype is a must when submit a file. I used it in Laravel 5.0 and everything was ok why ij Laravel 5.1 did not work.

Answer (score 0):

When using laravel 5.1, you should use:

```
dd(\Request::all());
```

Or getting the file:

```
dd(\Request::file('main_img));
```

Getting specific input:

```
dd(\Request::input('example_input_field'));
```

Code should look like something like this:

```
    {!! Form::open(array(
            'url'   => url('upload'),
            'method'=> 'POST',
            'files' => true)) 
    !!}

    {!! Form::file('file', array('type'=>'file')) !!}

    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Caution: This example form uses: `"illuminate/html": "~5.0",` package

Comment: the same when put it in rule function in request the array is empty public function rules()
    {              dd(\Request::all());

Comment: the issue in image size: 4M when upload image less than 4M the validation success. but i see in php.ini upload_max_filesize = 64M what is the issue.

Comment: Are you using WAMP? If so, you also have to change the php.ini file located in : `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.X.X` (where x is your php version)